# Proof in lambda calculus that the successor function is injective

Tags: proof-writing, induction, lambda-calculus

I am new to lambda calculus and I am trying to proof that the successor function $suc := \lambda nfx.f (n f x)$ is injective, i.e. that $suc \, a = suc \, b \to a = b$ for all $a$ and $b$.

My argument goes as follows:

$suc \, a = suc \, b$

$\lambda fx.f (a f x) = \lambda fx.f (b f x)$

As both sides are equivalent, they have to yield the same result when applied to all $g$ and $y$.

$(\lambda fx.f (a f x) ) g y = (\lambda fx.f (b f x) ) g y$

$g (a g y) = g (b g y)$

As this holds for all $g$, it also holds when $g$ is injective. Therefore the arguments of $g$ must be equivalent.

$a g y = b g y$

This states that $a$ and $b$ yield the same result for all $g$ and all $y$. Therefore $a$ and $b$ must be equivalent.

Does this argumentation make any sense? Or how does one go about proofing equivalences in lambda calculus?

Comment: Your argument assumes that $g$ is injective, but then drops that assumption, which doesn't look right. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790249/lambda-calculus-predecessor-function-reduction-steps. It should help you show that successor followed by predecessor is the identity.

Comment: @RobArthan The argumentations presented in the thread you linked, all circle around the f^n part of Church numerals. Which smells a lot like needing induction to proof anything related to it. However, I do not have access to induction unless I can proof that the successor function is injective (and that 0 is the successor of no number). Looks like the cat is biting its own tail. However, I will invest more thought into the hint you gave me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The article gives a $\lambda$-term for the predecessor function, the left inverse of successor. Using that definition, you should be able to show that $\mathit{pre}(\mathit{suc}(x))$ $\beta$-reduces to $x$, implying that $\mathit{suc}$ is injective.

Comment: ... However, I think showing that $\mathit{pre}(\mathit{suc}(x))$ $\beta$-reduces to $x$ likely requires the assumption that $x$ is a Church numeral and that will mean you need to prove it by induction.

Comment: Your last observation about the necessity of induction is what stopped me in my tracks.

Comment: @RobArthan Would you be willing to sum up your comments as an answer so I can accept it?